# Using Apex to mimic semantic string versioning (to validate “increment only” logic to a text field that represents semantic version

Tags: managed-package, unlocked-package, versioning, version-control

Hey versioning experts,

Has anyone used Apex to construct a semantic version bumper?

Im looking to implement an Apex-driven "versioning" concept to a custom app, functioning somewhat similar to versioning forms/validations in SFDC Packaging,  but specific to salesforce *Records*, *not Packages*.

The idea is that records would have semantic versions like packages but stored in a custom text field, "`SemVersion__c`".
The user would be allowed to increment it using semantic versioning standards so that version strings are comparable (major minor patch qualifier etc.) and always-incrementing

Thanks for the collaboration!

Comment: I haven't explored using it against Apex records, but the native [`Version`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_version.htm) class could be really useful here. It will give you a container for you major, minor, and patch numbers. Plus a `compareTo(version)` method.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One option would be to use the native [`Version`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_version.htm) class that Apex provides.

This will give you major, minor, and patch numbers.

Plus there is an existing `compareTo(version)` method.